# Redux is not updating component even after returning new state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-state-management

I am new to redux.
What I am trying to do is to **fetch auth status from redux** state and **accordingly render my components** if auth is true then render home else login but every time **redux is returning undefined as auth state**.

This is my component

```
import axios from 'axios';
import jsonwebtoken from 'jsonwebtoken';
import Login from './Containers/Login'
import Home from './Containers/Home'
import {connect } from 'react-redux'
const server = 'http://localhost:5000/api/';
function getCookie(cname) {
    let name = cname + "=";
    let ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        let c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
function App({auth, setstate}) {
  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchdata = async ()=>{
      const token = getCookie('token');
      let loggedInUser = {};
      if (token !== '') {
        try {
            loggedInUser = await jsonwebtoken.verify(token, 'shhhhh')._doc;
            const res1 = await axios.post(server + 'userlist/getlist', { id: loggedInUser._id });
            const res2 = await axios.post(server + 'usertodo/gettodo', { listid: loggedInUser.defaultListid });
            if (res1.data.error === null && res2.data.error === null) {
                const { lists } = res1.data;
                const { todos } = res2.data;
                const newState = {
                    isAuth: true,
                    loggedInUser,
                    selectedListid: loggedInUser.defaultListid,
                    todos,
                    lists
                }
                setstate(newState)
            }
            else{
              console.log(res1.data.error, res2.data.error);
              setstate({
                isAuth:false
              })
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
      }
    }
    fetchdata();
  },[setstate, auth])

  return (auth ? <Home/>:<Login/>);
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
  return {
    auth: state.isAuth
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
  return {
    setstate: async(newState)=> dispatch({type:'SET_STATES', newState})
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

=========================================================================

this is my initialState

```
    isAuth: false,
    loggedInUser: null,
    selectedListid: null,
    todos: [],
    lists: []
}
```

and reducer

```
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_STATES':
        {
            const { newState } = action
            return {
                ...state,
                ...newState
            }
        }
        default:
            return state;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) instead of having all the async logic in your component and instead of using connect you can use the useSelector and useDispatch hooks from react-redux. You should also make action creator functions and store action types in constants. Having only a SET_STATE action that sets the entire state defeats the purpose of redux, try to create actions that do a specific thing.

I am not getting undefined as auth state using your exact code so there must be something missing in your question. Did you try checking the redux devtools and can you provide us with the information there like what is the state, what actions are dispatched, what changes did they make to the state? There may be something wrong with the fetch code as well so it'll end up in catch but then nothing should happen and you auth should not be undefined as it is set in initial state.

If you still have trouble getting your code to work properly then I suggest adding a [runnable snippet](https://gist.github.com/amsterdamharu/cf93d154958207b4f938ec58e45ffbde) to your question that reproduces the problem or create a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)

Below is your redux code working as expected, I added an extra check if auth is false so it won't authenticate when you are already authenticated:

```js
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;

const initialState = {
  isAuth: false,
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_STATES': {
      const { newState } = action;
      return {
        ...state,
        ...newState,
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
      () => (next) => (action) => next(action)
    )
  )
);
//fake getCookie
const getCookie = () => 'token';
function App({ auth, setstate }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    //removed async because SO has ancient babel
    const fetchdata = () => {
      const token = getCookie('token');
      if (token !== '' && auth === false) {
        //only do this if not authenticated
        const newState = {
          isAuth: true,
        };
        setstate(newState);
      }
    };
    fetchdata();
  }, [setstate, auth]);

  return <div>auth is: {String(auth)}</div>;
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    auth: state.isAuth,
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    //removed async because SO as ancient babel
    setstate: (newState) =>
      dispatch({ type: 'SET_STATES', newState }),
  };
};
const ConnectedApp = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedApp />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```